# No se cargan los mapas en ninguna aplicación

Tags: android, google-maps

Cuando compilo una aplicación que carga un mapa de GoogleMaps, éste no se carga,se queda la pantalla en gris, mostrando el logo de Google.
He probado con diferentes ejemplos y me pasa igual, así que será problema de la configuración de Android Studio, he probado de todo, ya estoy para desinstalarlo y volver a instalarlo, pero antes me gustaría saber qué ha pasado.
Alguien tiene alguna idea por probar?? Gracias!!

Comment: Has puesto el api key en tu app?

Comment: Como comenta @Pikoh tiene que ser problema de la Key. Ten en cuenta que si estás compilando proyectos de ejemplo de Internet, no funcionará debido a que una Api Key no funciona compilándose en distintos ordenadores.

Comment: Mi aplicacion tenía Key, probé de pedir otra, la cambié y igual. Gracias de todos modos!!

Comment: @MartíAmatVila es seguro que es un problema de api key. Sigue [estos pasos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=es-419) uno por uno

Comment: Debes añadir la información de los logs. S el error no se puede reproducir  la pregunta será cerrada.

Comment: No añadí logs porqué tampoco tube ningún mensaje de error al compilar.

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema que tienes es que no te carga el mapa en Android Studio es normal, Android Studio no reproduce los mapas, sin embargo si conectas por USB un smartphone y lo usas de emulador si que debería de mostrártelos.

La otra opción es que no te funcione al instalar la APK que generas con Android Studio.

Si no te funciona en ningún caso es lo que te han dicho el resto de compañeros, has generado mal la Api-key.

Comment: Hola,me referia a que no carga el mapa ni en el emulador ni en el smartphone. He generado la Api-key en otras ocasiones y me funcionó correctamente. Probaré otra vez, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

de nuevo. Al final dí con el problema... Borré mi MapFragment del proyecto, con su MapActivity y referencias en Manifest, y cargué un nuevo MapFragment, pidiendo una nueva ApiKey y funcionó.
Seguramente el problema provenia de copiar y pegar código desde otro PC donde tb desarrollo el mismo proyecto, detectaria que no tenia la misma ApiKey. Lo mismo pasaba al intentar cargar mapas directamente de ejemplos de Github.
Gracias!!